# Pagination: Limit the page number on small screen devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-pagination

On a small screen device (> 641 px) my pagination should look like [image]

and on medium and above screen size (< 641 px) pagination should look like [image]

I am using 'paginga - jQuery Pagination Plugin v0.8.1' and also wrote jQuery to achieve this, but I am unable to get the required result Please can anyone help me? Below is the plugin.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined)
{
    "use strict";

        var pluginName = "paginga",
            defaults = {
                itemsPerPage: 3,
                itemsContainer: ".items",
                item: "> div",
                page: 1,
                nextPage: ".nextPage",
                previousPage: ".previousPage", 
                firstPage: ".firstPage",
                lastPage: ".lastPage",
                pageNumbers: ".pageNumbers",
                maxPageNumbers: true,
                currentPageClass: "active",
                pager: ".pager",
                autoHidePager: true,
                scrollToTop: {
                    offset: 15,
                    speed: 100,
                },
                history: false,
                historyHashPrefix: "page-"
            };

        // The actual plugin constructor
        function paginga(element, options)
        {
            this.element = element;
            this.settings = $.extend( true, {}, defaults, options );
            this._defaults = defaults;
            this._name = pluginName;
            this._ready = false;
            this.currentPage = this.settings.page;
            this.items = $(this.element).find(this.settings.itemsContainer + " " + this.settings.item);
            this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.settings.itemsPerPage);
           // this.totalPages = 6;


            //if(this.totalPages <= 1)
           // {
            //    $(this.element).find(this.settings.pager).hide();

           // }
           // else
            //{
                this.init();
           // }
        }

        $.extend(paginga.prototype,
        {
            init: function()
            {
                console.log('in lib');
                this.bindEvents();
                this.showPage();

                if(this.settings.history)
                {
                    var plugin = this;

                    if(window.location.hash)
                    {
                        var hash = parseInt(window.location.hash.substring(plugin.settings.historyHashPrefix.length + 1), 10);

                        if(hash <= plugin.totalPages && hash > 0)
                        {
                            plugin.currentPage = hash;
                            plugin.showPage.call(plugin);
                        }
                    }

                    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event)
                    {
                        plugin.currentPage = event && event.state && event.state.page ? event.state.page : plugin.settings.page;
                        plugin.showPage.call(plugin);
                    });
                }

                this._ready = true;
            },
            bindEvents: function()
            {
                var plugin = this,
                    element = $(plugin.element),
                    previousElement = element.find(plugin.settings.previousPage),
                    nextElement = element.find(plugin.settings.nextPage),
                    firstElement = element.find(plugin.settings.firstPage),
                    lastElement = element.find(plugin.settings.lastPage);

                previousElement.on("click", function()
                {
                    plugin.showPreviousPage.call(plugin);
                });

                nextElement.on("click", function()
                {
                    plugin.showNextPage.call(plugin);
                });

                firstElement.on("click", function()
                {
                    plugin.showFirstPage.call(plugin);
                });

                lastElement.on("click", function()
                {
                    plugin.showLastPage.call(plugin);
                });
            },
            showPreviousPage: function()
            {
                this.currentPage--;

                if(this.currentPage <= 1)
                {
                    this.currentPage = 1;
                }

                this.setHistoryUrl();
                this.showPage();
            },
            showNextPage: function()
            {
                this.currentPage++;

                if(this.currentPage >= this.totalPages)
                {
                    this.currentPage = this.totalPages;
                }

                this.setHistoryUrl();
                this.showPage();
            },
            showFirstPage: function()
            {
                this.currentPage = 1;

                this.setHistoryUrl();
                this.showPage();
            },
            showLastPage: function()
            {
                this.currentPage = this.totalPages;

                this.setHistoryUrl();
                this.showPage();
                this.showPage();
            },
            showPage: function()
            {
                var firstItem = (this.currentPage * this.settings.itemsPerPage) - this.settings.itemsPerPage,
                    lastItem = firstItem + this.settings.itemsPerPage;

                $.each(this.items, function(index, item)
                {
                    if(index >= firstItem && index < lastItem)
                    {
                        $(item).show();

                        return true;
                    }

                    $(item).hide();
                });

                var plugin = this,
                    element = $(plugin.element),
                    previousElement = element.find(plugin.settings.previousPage),
                    nextElement = element.find(plugin.settings.nextPage),
                    firstElement = element.find(plugin.settings.firstPage),
                    lastElement = element.find(plugin.settings.lastPage);

                if(plugin._ready && plugin.settings.scrollToTop && (element.offset().top - plugin.settings.scrollToTop.offset) < $(window).scrollTop())
                {
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: (element.offset().top - plugin.settings.scrollToTop.offset) }, plugin.settings.scrollToTop.speed);
                }

                if(this.currentPage <= 1)
                {
                    previousElement.addClass("disabled");
                    firstElement.addClass("disabled");
                }
                else
                {
                    previousElement.removeClass("disabled");
                    firstElement.removeClass("disabled");
                }

                if(this.currentPage >= this.totalPages)
                {
                    nextElement.addClass("disabled");
                    lastElement.addClass("disabled");
                }
                else
                {
                    nextElement.removeClass("disabled");
                    lastElement.removeClass("disabled");
                }

                var pager = element.find(this.settings.pager),
                    pageNumbers = pager.find(this.settings.pageNumbers);

                if(pageNumbers)
                {
                    pageNumbers.html("");

                    var firstPage = 1;
                    var lastPage = this.totalPages;

                    if(this.settings.maxPageNumbers)
                    {
                        var offset = Math.ceil((this.settings.maxPageNumbers - 1) / 2);

                        firstPage = Math.max(1, this.currentPage - offset);
                        lastPage = Math.min(this.totalPages, this.currentPage + offset);

                        if(lastPage - firstPage < this.settings.maxPageNumbers - 1)
                        {
                            if(firstPage <= offset)
                            {
                                lastPage = Math.min(this.totalPages, firstPage + this.settings.maxPageNumbers - 1);
                            }
                            else if(lastPage > this.totalPages - offset)
                            {
                                firstPage = Math.max(1, lastPage - this.settings.maxPageNumbers + 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var pageNumber = firstPage; pageNumber <= lastPage; pageNumber++)
                    {
                        var className = pageNumber == this.currentPage ? this.settings.currentPageClass : "";

                        pageNumbers.append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' data-page='" + pageNumber + "' class='" + className + "'>" + pageNumber + "</a>");
                    }

                    pageNumbers.find("a").on("click", function()
                    {
                        plugin.currentPage = $(this).data("page");

                        plugin.setHistoryUrl.call(plugin);
                        plugin.showPage.call(plugin);
                    });
                }
            },
            setHistoryUrl: function()
            {
                var plugin = this;

                if(plugin._ready && plugin.settings.history && "pushState" in history)
                {
                    history.pushState({ page: this.currentPage }, null, '#' + plugin.settings.historyHashPrefix + this.currentPage);
                }
            }
        });

        $.fn[pluginName] = function(options)
        {
            return this.each(function()
            {
                if(!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName))
                {
                    $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new paginga(this, options));
                }
            });
        };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The jQuery i wrote:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 641) {
        $(".paginate").paginga({
            itemsPerPage: 2,
            maxPageNumbers: 2,
            page: 1
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".paginate").paginga({
            itemsPerPage: 2,
            maxPageNumbers: 6
        });
    }
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if (windowWidth < 641) {
            $(".paginate").paginga({
                itemsPerPage: 2,
                maxPageNumbers: 2
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.pager').load();
            $(".paginate").paginga({
                itemsPerPage: 6,
                maxPageNumbers: 6
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Any other jquery plugin, which I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update the value of 'windowWidth' when the resize event is triggered?
I can't really test it without the code of the pagination generation in your specific case, but I think this could help. Let me know if that's not the case.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width(); //add this line of code
    if (windowWidth < 641) {
        $(".paginate").paginga({
            itemsPerPage: 2,
            maxPageNumbers: 2
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.pager').load();
        $(".paginate").paginga({
            itemsPerPage: 6,
            maxPageNumbers: 6
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not working. Till 640px it shows 2 pages but as soon as I make the screen size as 641px I still see 3 pages instead of 6. Is this because of  "itemsPerPage: 3" in the plugin?

Comment: I can't think of any other reason than this: after you redefine your paginga paginator, you need to redraw/refresh the paginator. I'll check if the plugin has a built in event for that.

Comment: refreshing the page on view port change is not allowed, instead can we refresh the div only, sound good?

Comment: That's what I mean, you only need the component to refresh, something like: `$(".paginate").paginga('redraw');'` but the thing is: the plugin is poorly documented and doesn't mention anythin about a refresh trigger/event..

Comment: Any other jquery plugin, which I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I came across [this one](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) while searching. At least this one is a bit more documented, maybe it could help?